# How do the delegate methods in this Ruby class work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need some help to understand this Ruby code. The more layman the better.

The method `cancelled?` delegates to `current_state`, and that will try and fetch an event where `state == 'cancelled'`. If it does not find one, it will return the first element in the `STATES` array, which defaults to open.

1. How does the `current_state` know we want cancelled? What if we want `incomplete?` or `open?` We're not providing any arguments when we call `self.cancelled?`.
2. How do the delegate methods return a boolean value? `current_state` does not return a boolean. It always returns an `Event` or `STATES[0]`.

Obviously I'm missing something. Here's [the example app](https://github.com/railscasts/392-a-tour-of-state-machines/blob/master/orders-events/app/models/order.rb) I'm learning from.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events

  STATES = %w[incomplete open cancelled shipped]
  delegate :incomplete?, :open?, :cancelled?, to: :current_state

  def current_state
    (events.last.try(:state) || STATES.first).inquiry
  end

  def cancel
    events.create! state: 'cancelled' if open?
  end

  def resume
    events.create! state: 'open' if cancelled?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delegate` can be thought of as "send these methods to this target", so

```
self.cancelled?
```

expands to

```
(events.last.try(:state) || STATES.first).inquiry.cancelled?
```

and this is the inquiry method: http://apidock.com/rails/String/inquiry

So basically, it checks that the last event state in the data model (or the default "incomplete") has a string value equal to the method name (minus question mark), and returns true if it matches.